# Moving an Xcode project to a different machine

Tags: xcode, git

I have an Xcode project in my machine and I'm using Git from version control. Now I pushed the project to the server and want to fetch it from a different machine. The problem is, many paths seem to be absolute and so the project does not compile on the other machine. How can I set the paths on *my* machine, so that after committing, fetching on the other machine will work fine?

Comment: Go through the project settings and make them relative paths?

Comment: Are those all the paths there are?

Comment: Should be, unless you have absolute paths in your source files.

Comment: No, I don't... But then there's no way to do this automatically? I hardly think that doing it manually is a sane approach

Comment: There's no way to automatically adjust them that I know of. I always take care to make everything relative in the first place.

Comment: If your project is in source control (git) then simply check out a fresh copy on the new machine. You shouldn't need to copy anything from the old machine.

Comment: @maddy, I cloned the project. The project does not exist on the other machine yet.

Comment: This even tells "Use of undeclared type 'UIViewController'". And I changed all paths I could find in the project settings.

Comment: One thing I don't get: what exactly could I have done to keep the paths relative? I hardly ever entered any path at all.

Comment: Maybe it's important to mention this is Xcode 6 Beta.